# How to replace double period with single period in a file with SED or AWK?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

What's the recommended way to do this and save it to a new file?
I tried

`sed -i 's/.././g' /tmp/folder/domains.new`

But it replaced single periods as well..

Comment: I'm surprised you're only mentioning the replacement of single periods, that's a VERY destructive command: `echo hello world | sed 's/.././g'`

Comment: Please read the tutorial at www.regular-expressions.info. Every programmer should know the basics of regular expressions.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for `tr`.  All you need is `tr -s . < inputfile`  -- it doesn't do in-place substitution, though.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much. I will check it out. I am insanely new to this side of bash even though I've been managing servers the hard way for a year. I'm getting more efficient. Glenn, It did destroy more than expected. Devnull, Thanks!

Comment: @devnull the `tr` solution is definitely worth considering but it could come back to bite the OP in future if, for example, some day he has a sequence of 3 `.`s in his input and expects the output to be 2 `.`s.

Comment: @EdMorton  4 consecutive `.`s would be replaced with both the answers to this post.   I'm not sure what the expectation is (was).  That was another reason to simply put it in a comment.

Comment: The OP asked to replace 2 `.`s with 1 `.`. With the sed solution 3 or 4 `.`s would become 2 `.`s as expected. With the `tr` solution any sequence of 2 or more `.`s would become 1 `.`. That might be fine, I just think it's worth giving the OP a heads up in case he's testing today with input files that only have 1 or 2 contiguous `.`s

Comment: I am not so much of a mind reader so as to assume what _n_ number of consecutive `.`s should transform into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A period is a RE metacharacter so you need to escape it to have it taken literally:

```
sed 's/\.\././g' oldfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23523855/970195) has the right answer. Here is another way to ensure that RE metacharacters are taken literally (wrap them inside character classes):

```
sed -i 's/[.][.]/./g' /tmp/folder/domains.new
```

or

```
sed -i 's/[.]\{2\}/./g' /tmp/folder/domains.new
```

or use `-E` option to enable extended regex to prevent escaping `{` and `}`.

```
sed -i -E 's/[.]{2}/./g' /tmp/folder/domains.new
```

Note that in the replacement part, `.` and other metacharacters are always considered literal and not special.

Comment: The replacement part has metacharacters of its own: `&` is replaced by the text that the pattern matched;  backreferences (`\1`, `\2`, ...); GNU sed, case conversion (`\L`, `\l`, `\U`, `\u`, `\E`) ([documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command))